# How does using a 60Hz device on a 50Hz supply affect it?

Tags: ac, frequency

I've two Vibro Graver electric engravers (120V 60Hz) with me. I gave one to a friend who recently moved to another country. He got a step down converter from 220V to 110V but then he noticed the frequency used there is 50Hz.

What would the effects of using the device on a 110V 50Hz supply when the device is meant to be used on 120V 60Hz supply. Does the 10Hz difference cause any damage?

Edit: The voltage is stepped down from 220V 50Hz to 110V 50Hz
[Img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHV1c.jpg)

[image: IMG 2]

Comment: Likely will go unnoticed...And 120V to 110V stepdown? I doubt it is needed as well.

Comment: So, its safe to go ahead? I'm slightly confused because a person told me yesterday that sometimes inductive devices don't like frequency changes much. Is it true?

Comment: That's true. The question is how "much". Best thing would be to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Thanx mate. But I highly doubt if that company even exists anymore.

Comment: Depends on what the motor is. It may run 17% slower. BUt I doubt it.

Comment: @Trevor Are vibro-engravers using motors? Probably some kind of linear actuators... And as far as I understand from the regulator, the frequency is adjustable..

Comment: @EugeneSh. oh is it.. I thought it was a dremmel type thingy. I didnt even see the script writing LOL. Either way if it's adjustable it wont be synchronous. Interesting they specifically added the work ONLY to the voltage numbers though.

Comment: The adjuster is labelled "stroke" so I would expect it to adjust the amplitude of the vibration rather than the frequency. I suspect @Trevor is right about the 17% slower.

Comment: Right enough @Finbarr.. Tell him to plug it in and see and get back to us. Yes inductive devices have frequency dependent characteristics, but 50-60hz change is trivial. 50hz-1khz would be a different story.  It won't hurt it for sure.

Comment: @Trevor. Yeah. I've asked him to try connecting it and see how it goes. I just wasn't sure how the results would like. If there is any immediate damage?

Comment: If @Trevor is right, it won't work that well as it will vibrate a bit slower. But I guess there is no way to actually compare it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  I've tried to run a 60 Hz electric razor on 50 Hz...It did not sound like the motor/actuator was happy. I suspect this kind of machine could have similar issues. For example, the mechanics could be designed to be somewhat resonant at 60 Hz.

Comment: @ThePhoton I agree, but you need a reference to know that it doesn't sound right. For example I have no idea how this thing should sound like :)

Comment: @ThePhoton He did try with the stepped down 120V 50Hz and he experienced similar to what you mentioned. It was a lot louder and was getting warm really quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons you may have trouble.

50Hz into 60Hz-designed inductors can *always* be a problem, depending on how conservatively the original 60Hz design was with respect to saturation. If saturation is more than 20% away at 60Hz, then you'll get away with it at 50Hz. If closer, then the core could saturate, drawing many times more current. You can avoid this by transforming the voltage down to 83% of the rated voltage, so 100v, but of course this will reduce the power available.

Vibratory motors will often use a mechanical resonance between the mass of the armature and the compliance of the spring used to support it, to make up for the poor efficiency of that type of motor. If that's the case with this one, then the 50/60 difference could render it completely ineffective. Try it and see.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I agree with what you have said. The device is louder and gets warm faster on 50Hz. So the only cheap option he has now is getting a 12V DC to 120V 60Hz inverter. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B074DV8YKJ/ref=dp_sp_detail2?psc=1

Comment: Also I'm confused about Howard reversible auto transformers that have both 110V/220V conversion can run at both 50/60Hz frequencies without over-heating. As it is also an inductive device like a motor. What could be the possible design changes they have adopted?

Comment: @RahulSalin A multi-frequency transformer is designed to be OK at the worst frequency for each specification. So for instance the core area is designed for no saturation at 50Hz operation, it will be better at 60Hz. The core material would be rated for core hysteresis losses at 60Hz, and the laminations would be thin enough for eddy current losses at 60Hz, and it then both will be fine at 50Hz. It's not difficult if it goes in at the original design. We often used 50-400Hz rated transformers, consider audio range transformers in tube amplifiers!

Comment: @Rahul, is this $90 12v-inverter the better option? Wouldn't be better if he buys an engraver in the country where he's living now?

Comment: @mguima :D Only if it was just the engraver. He seemed to have taken some other appliances/devices too. He already ordered a $200 3000W 115V 60Hz inverter he told me.