# Using 120 VAC 60 Hz battery charger with 50 Hz AC

Tags: transformer, frequency, mains

I live in Australia (220-240 VAC, 50 Hz mains). On a recent trip to the United States (110-120 VAC, 60 Hz mains), I purchased some battery-powered tools that came with a charger. The charger has this printed on it:

[image: Battery Charger Data Plate]

I have a transformer for converting Australian mains to 110 VAC:

[image: Transformer Data Plate]

It is just a transformer, not a frequency converter.

Is there any reason to be concerned about putting 50 Hz AC into my new charger? My thinking is that there is not, because the charger is converts the AC current to DC anyway, before feeding it into the battery.

Problems with AC frequency have to do mainly with induction motors, I think. I found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336504/how-does-using-a-60hz-device-on-a-50hz-supply-affect-it) question, and some others, that seem to confirm that.

I can open up the charger to see what circuitry is in there, but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the frequency to be much of a problem.

Comment: The charger is invariably an SMPS system. You should be fine just using your voltage convertor transformer.

Comment: No issues! Go for it.

Comment: There's a slight chance that it'll have trouble, but if it does it'll take the form of a them dying quietly, but not bursting into flames and burning down your garage.  At worst they'll break and you'll have to see if DeWalt has a presence is Oz and will sell you some adapters that are correct for your situation.  At best I'm overly concerned, and they'll last for the life of the tools.

Comment: As a generalization for future use, 50Hz equipment has a much higher probability of working on a 60Hz supply than vice versa, since the 50Hz equipment requires a minimum inductance that exceeds that needed by 60Hz equipment.  I would just be sure to monitor it the first several times you use it. 60Hz transformers tend to underperform on 50Hz service.  All of that said, you're probably fine in this case.  Note that small transformers tend to have awful load regulation, so you might want to double check your open circuit and full load voltages just to be sure of what you're feeding it.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much every small DeWalt battery charger that I have taken apart uses a capacitor-type power supply.  If yours is the same, it will work just fine from 50 Hz but the charge rate will be reduced by the ratio (50/60).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is surely noticed that alternating current will in any case be transformed into direct current. no worries.
As stated above, the downside may be a decrease in the charge rate.
If to alter, then it would be possible to check what stabilizers are, if low-powered, then instead of them you can install a "full-fledged" stabilizer with a radiator in the case. As an option.

Comment: Why do you state that the "direct current will in any case be transformed into alternating current", surely you mean the reverse...

Comment: yes, this is my boner, I apologize

Comment: Well done for editing it.

Comment: @MichaelSelect - Hi, you seem to be thinking about linear power supplies, as you say that "*you can install a "full-fledged" stabilizer* [I think you mean "regulator"] *with a radiator* [I think you mean "heatsink"] *in the case*". It is common for SMPS not to have output *regulators*, but to use other techniques.  Also for a battery charger connected to the mains, like this one, I would not advise the OP to start changing components and fitting heatsinks, all of which would invalidate the original safety approvals.  After (the current) sentence 2, most of this answer seems like a guess :-(